# About lifetime of Rust. Why the following code can be compiled

Tags: rust

According to my thoughts, the value referenced by result may be invalid, why can it still be compiled?

My code is this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("hello world");
    let result;
    {
        let b = "yeah!";
        result = longest(a.as_str(), b);
    }
    println!("{}", result);
}

fn longest<'a>(x:&'a str, y:&'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

But When I change the

```
let b = "yeah!";
result = longest(a.as_str(), b);
```

to

```
let b = String::from("yeah!");
result = longest(a.as_str(), b.as_str());
```

It will not compile. I get a Error:

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:38
  |
6 |         result = longest(a.as_str(), b.as_str());
  |                                      ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     }
  |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
8 |     println!("{}", result);
  |                    ------ borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `lifetime`
```

Comment: Not a Rust expert, but I think it's that [string literals have static lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-static-lifetime).  So in your first example, `a` and `b` both live long enough to be passed to the `println!`, and thus so does the return value of `longest`.  In your second example, `b`'s lifetime ends at the end of the inner block, which is too soon.

Comment: In the first example, `b` has type `&'static str` so it lives indefinitely. In the second example, `b` only lives until the closing brace, so is no longer available for the `println`.